# Does mediafilesegmenter support sample encryption?

Tags: encryption, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to segment and sample-encrypt a MP4 file with mediafilesegmenter. I use the command below:

$ mediafilesegmenter -k  -r myMovie.mp4

It created segments with AES-128 encryption instead of sample-AES. Anybody know if mediafilesegmenter does sample-encryption?